# Apache Camel: How I can create AWS SQS and subscribe to SNS topic

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I want to create AWS SQS and then subscribe it to an existing SNS topic. For use [this approach](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/aws-sns-component.html#_create_a_subscription_between_an_aws_sns_topic_and_an_aws_sqs_queue), from Camel documentation, I must know a queue URL.

```java
//create SQS
from("aws-sqs://MyQueue?amazonSQSClient=#client&delay=5000&maxMessagesPerPoll=5")
.startupOrder(1)
.to("mock:result");

//create SNS and subscribe to SQS
from("direct:start")
.startupOrder(2)
.to("aws-sns://test-camel-sns1?amazonSNSClient=#amazonSNSClient&amazonSQSClient=#amazonSQSClient&subscribeSNStoSQS=true&queueUrl=https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/780410022472/MyQueue");
```

But I want to use previously created SQS (I know the name of SQS) and I don't know the account value(780410022472).
How can I create SQS and subscribe to SNS without additional information(like an account value) by Camel?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the AWS account via CLI, you could simply list all existing queues as follows:

```
aws sqs list-queues
```

This will return the SQS queue URLs as follows:

```
https://queue.amazonaws.com/80398EXAMPLE/MyQueue
```

In the above example, the account number would be `80398EXAMPLE`.

You could also get the account details for the current IAM user/role using the following command:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

This will return the account number with the `Account` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had implemented a subscription using AmazonSNS and AmazonSQS (from aws-java-sdk libraries). But I want to use a more simple approach by Camel Routes to eliminate using SDK components.

Comment: I understand that you want to use Camel's AWS components for integrating with SNS and SQS, but I thought your initial question was about how to determine the account number for the `queueUrl ` parameter that is needed as part of the component URI?

Comment: Sorry. Maybe the question wasn't clear. I edited my question. I want to find a simple solution using only Camel by the specified name of the SNS topic and SQS queue. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't tried this solution on AWS, but I tested it on LocalStack and it seems to work properly:

```java
    class LocalStack extends org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create("dummy", "dummy");

            bindToRegistry("amazonSQSClient",
                    SqsClient.builder()
                            .endpointOverride(new URI("http://localhost:4566"))
                            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                            .build());

            bindToRegistry("amazonSNSClient",
                    SnsClient.builder()
                            .endpointOverride(new URI("http://localhost:4566"))
                            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                            .build());

            from("aws2-sqs://MyQueue?amazonSQSClient=#amazonSQSClient&autoCreateQueue=true").to("mock:result");

            Endpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("aws2-sqs://MyQueue?amazonSQSClient=#amazonSQSClient&autoCreateQueue=true");
            Assert.assertTrue(endpoint instanceof Sqs2Endpoint);

            SqsClient sqsClient = ((Sqs2Endpoint) endpoint).getClient();
            String url = sqsClient.getQueueUrl(builder -> builder.queueName("MyQueue")).queueUrl();

            from("direct:start")
                    .to("aws2-sns://active_inventory-int-public-outgoing-notifications" +
                            "?autoCreateTopic=true" +
                            "&amazonSNSClient=#amazonSNSClient" +
                            "&subscribeSNStoSQS=true" +
                            "&queueUrl=" + url);
        }
```

The code should be self-explanatory. The calls to `bindToRegistry` are needed just because I'm working on LocalStack, otherwise the default should be fine.